# How to combine two cursors in DB2

Tags: sql, select, db2, multirow

I have two cursors as below:

```
EXEC SQL                                      
     DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR               
     SELECT  DISTINCT FIELD_1                  
     FROM    TABLE                  
     WHERE   FIELD_2 BETWEEN :MAX_DATE
                        AND '9999-12-31'      
           AND   FIELD_3 =  :VALUE 
     WITH UR                                  
     FOR FETCH ONLY                           
END-EXEC

EXEC SQL                                      
     DECLARE C2 CURSOR FOR               
     SELECT  DISTINCT FIELD_1                  
     FROM    TABLE                  
     WHERE   FIELD_2 BETWEEN :MIN_DATE
                        AND '9999-12-31'      
           AND   FIELD_3 =  :VALUE 
     WITH UR                                  
     FOR FETCH ONLY                           
END-EXEC
```

Both the cursors are pointing to same table. How can I combine the two cursors? Please let me know a way to combine the two tables.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "cobine" the two cursors? Do you want the union of both result sets? Or the intersection? Or something else?

Comment: Like in place of using two cursors, can we use one cursor

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. You could combine the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to combine the predicates of both cursors, of course you could do. Combine the `WHERE` clauses:

```
EXEC SQL                                      
     DECLARE C1 CURSOR FOR               
     SELECT  DISTINCT FIELD_1                  
     FROM    TABLE                  
     WHERE   FIELD_2 BETWEEN :MIN_DATE
                        AND :MAX_DATE
           AND   FIELD_3 =  :VALUE 
     WITH UR                                  
     FOR FETCH ONLY                           
END-EXEC
```

Your example in the question had both min and max values in a range with `9999-12-31` which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: 'DISTINCT' is taking too long time for execution. Can we use anything else instead of 'DISTINCT' so that we can save CPU time and Cost.

Comment: i have a cursor like this with 'DISTINCT' clause. This cursor is taking more time to execute in Open Cursor statement. please tell me a way to optimize. Can i use 'ORDER BY' or 'GROUP BY' here

Comment: EXEC SQL                                             
     DECLARE CSR CURSOR FOR                  
         SELECT DISTINCT                             
                A.FIELD1                        
               ,C.FIELD2                            
           FROM TABLE1 A                      
               ,TABLE2     B                      
               ,TABLE3    C                      
          WHERE A.FIELD3= :VALUE....